# ASP.NET MVC RSS feed datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I get this datetime format for an RSS feed?

```
Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What RSS feed? Where is the date coming from? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Comment: Plz view the example  in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want  `DateTime.Now.ToString("r")`,
where the 'r' indicates formatting following the [RFC1123](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.rfc1123pattern.aspx) pattern.

It will not (always) display an offset as +000, it will use 'GMT' and other standardized tz names.

As far as I can tell this one of the rare case where you don't have to specify an IFromatProvider.